# C# Silverlight - When do Resource Dictionaries get created?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am working on a Silverlight 4 project where I get a memory leak because every time some xaml views are loaded they create their own instance of a class that then gets hooked with event triggers and don't get garbage collected. Removing the event listeners has proved too tricky under the circumstances for me to handle it that way. So Instead I want the instance of the class to be re-used every time the xaml view loads.

To do this I was planning on adding a Resource Dictionary to each project that this error is occurring in. My concern though is that I don't know when this Resource Dictionary will be created. When the solution first loads will it load the project then the resource dictionary, immediately creating the class for use? Or will it wait until something asks for it and then create it. Will what actually happens create a copy of the class that gets re-used by everyone that accesses it(as in not another copy)?

I also realize I can place the resources in app.xaml but I need to add many such classes and it will really clutter up the area which shouldn't be bothered with this problem.

Comment: Is your concern avoiding allocating multiple resource dictionaries?

Comment: My concern is I have a rather large project that was passed on to me that I want to keep clean. Adding about 16 elements to the app.xaml resource dictionary that only get used in one place seems dirty and if anyone need to find out what they are they won't look there first. I know how to accomplish the task, I just want to keep relevant data grouped and prevent dispersing things I'll need throughout the solution. I've been reading though and might just implement a merged dictionary in order to keep it sorted.

Comment: Well if you use it multiple places unless you take steps to prevent it, separate copies will get allocated.  That's why I asked.

Comment: separate copies of the resource dictionary or separate copies of the custom class? MSDN has led me to believe that a custom class used in a resource dictionary will be re-used. I took that to mean the actual instance of the class will be re-used. I was going to go ahead and implement a merged dictionary with the app.xaml file unless someone had a cleaner implementation for me to use. And just define all the resources for those similar things in one resource dictionary file.

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer based on this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Christian Moser's [SharedResourceDictionary](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html) to avoid loading second copies of the dictionary itself or anything it contains.  This has saved us a long amount of load time in many controls.

Comment: I was reading the comments on that website and it seemed that people were having trouble implementing it in Silverlight 4, can you confirm that it works with SL4? I haven't had a chance to test it out yet due to a necessary side track in my to-do list.

Comment: Works just fine for me.  To test more deeply for you, I just tested a SharedResourceDictionary which contained another SharedResourceDictionary in SL4 and it found all the resources just fine.

Comment: in the process of implementing and checking for the memory leak (had a weird error interupt things) I left SharedResourceDictionary as a ResourceDictionary. Both worked to help with the memory leak (turned it from a flood to a lesser flood), to the same degree it seems. So it may be that in the newest version of Silverlight it does actually re-use resources for ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Nice.  I go both ways (WPF and Sliverlight) and share a lot of Xaml so I use Shared because it definitely saves a lot in WPF.